# Redirect Addresses to localhost by Pattern on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, vhosts, hosts

I'm not even 100% sure how to ask this question. The answer might be out there, but I can't find it.

So I've set up virtual hosts for my Mac and I do all my development locally on my computer. I have a `vhost` folder in my `Sites` folder, and I have a list of folders, such as:

```
recipes.cam
database.cam
sandbox.cam
codeigniter.cam
```

and in my `/etc/hosts` file I have an entry for each one:

```
# vhosts
127.0.0.1 recipes.cam
127.0.0.1 database.cam
127.0.0.1 sandbox.cam
127.0.0.1 codeigniter.cam
# ...
```

And this works great. When I go to http://recipes.cam in my browser, it shows the contents of the `~/Sites/vhosts/recipes.cam`.

**So this is my question**: Is there a way to have any address that end in `.cam` to redirect to localhost? So I don't have to create a new entry in `hosts` every time I add a new directory (it happens pretty often).

I tried `127.0.0.1 *.cam` in my `hosts` file, but it didn't work :-/

Comment: You could set up your own DNS server that responds to anything under the .cam domain. However, setting up such a server is off topic for Stack Overflow but might be appropriate on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll move my post to there. I'm a PHP/jQuery Developer and use this site often, so it's where I figured I'd start. Thanks.

Comment: This is something better implemented as a proxy server OR local dns server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution I've been able to find is DNSMasq.

Justin Carmony's blog post helped me set it up. His original question was more about why `.local` was so slow after upgrading OSX or something like that, but the solution was the same: DNSMasq.

http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/

Now, basically all *.cam address go to my local IP. I have it set up so all I have to do is create a folder, list test.cam and I'm off and running with a full LAMP stack.

Comment: I wrote up an updated version for Yosemite, using dnsmasq and ngnix (for proxying to different ports), fwiw.  Based on Justin & other's posts.

http://blog.inkandfeet.com/How-To-Get-Dev-Addresses-On-Mac-Os-X-1010-Yosemite-In-5-Simple-Steps